# Change colours of WebBrowser Control file explorer

Tags: .net, properties, webbrowser-control

So this question is NOT about how to change the background or other colours when viewing web pages.

I use this control as a file browser. The problem is that the properties are very limited and I am looking to change various aesthetic properties such as font, background colour etc. I have a feeling this might be complex as guessing windows leverages some api shared with Windows Explorer?

However, is there anyway to manipulate these properties?

EDIT: For clarity, some images below. The first shows my form with a WebBrowser control embedded - using it as a file browser. The second shows how I'd like to be able to customise it - changing, in the example, backcolor and font color (done in GIMP).

[image]

[image]

Comment: [How to change the default font of the form controls in Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636268/how-to-change-the-default-font-of-the-form-controls-in-visual-studio-ide) discussion may be relevant.

Comment: Can you put up a screenshot with markup of what specifically you would like to change?

Comment: @Leonid - thanks, but don't think that'll do it. I'd also need changes to be able to be applied at runtime (so user can change the WebBrowser properties - font, colors etc).

Comment: Alexander - have updated original post with some images. :)

Comment: That looks like the ShellFolderView that you get when you tell the web browser control to navigate to a File. So you want to change the background color of that yes?

Comment: Alexander - you got it. I suspected that might be the shell browser. Yes - would like to manipulate background color and font (size,color,family if poss) as a minimum. Control over other properties (highlight color etc) would be ideal. Lastly, would also like to keep any changes independent of Windows Explorer (although wondering whether this is possible - guessing if you change it programmatically, the changes likely to persist to anything using shell explorer?)

Comment: What you are talking about can be done. It would requite Pinvoke and dll import.  I am still working on it, but honestly anyone with the lower level C++ interop knowledge could answer this.

Comment: That's good to hear. Unfortunately, I have no c++ knowledge, nor would I know where to start using pinvoke to alter properties. Hope you can find a way... :)

Comment: Getting very close for setting the background color. I can get everywhere except where the items are. Will need to change the font color of the items so that they are readable though.

Comment: Sadly - that's really exciting stuff! Look forward to your discoveries. You made me want to start poking around too, but wouldn't know how/where to start!

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett - how goes it? Any joy?

Comment: Do you have a simple sample code that shows how you embed the webbrowser control or is it just a control you put on a Winform? WPF?

Comment: @SimonMourier - Just the usual winforms webbrowser control, added to form via designer view.

Comment: @stigzler can you share some code of how your webbrowser code looks like

Comment: Do you really need to use the webbrowser control? It seems to me that it is much easier to use a different control, like https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15059/C-File-Browser or 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-an-explorer-style-interface-with-the-listview-and-treeview

Comment: @Webruster - thanks for the reply. Not sure what code you are after. It's just a normal winforms webbrowser control added via designer view in Visual Studio. The question is more around how you modify the control itself to manipulate properties that aren't available through the control itself. Any code at the moment is just the usual manipulation of the control (browse, enable/disable etc)

Comment: @MartiendeJong - thanks. On the codeproject - I'm sure I looked at this as part of my researching options. Think I even put it into a test app and played around with it. For some reason, I chose not to go with it - but my testing was specifically around finding a browser control that retained all the functionality of windows explorer, but also allowed you to change colours. It might have been that this that you couldn't choose different views. Think also that you couldn't change the colors...